# SQL: Optimize query with multiple CASE statements

Tags: sql

I have a query with many CASE statements that runs for a very long time due to the number of rows. In my research I have not found a solution yet. Is there a way to write the CASE statements more efficiently and with better performance?

database: Oracle

table_a
table
table_y 
are all the same table where I SELECT from.

example data

| contract_number | product_description | product | damagenumber | date | internalname | payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product T-Shirt | product_name | 111 | 20210101 | Web | 30.20 |
| 2 | Product T-Shirt | product_name | 222 | 20210202 | Web | 19.38 |
| 3 | Product Hoodie | product_name2 | 333 | 20210215 | Store | 20.49 |
| 3 | Product Hoodie | product_name2 | 334 | 20210302 | Store | 15.99 |
| 5 | Product Hoodie | product_name2 | 123 | 20210120 | Telephone | 99.99 |

```
SELECT
    contract_number,
    product_description,
    product,
    CASE
        WHEN ( x.produkt = 'product_name'
               AND (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT damagenumber)
            FROM
                table z
            WHERE
                date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 6) AND sysdate
                AND internalname <> 'CONDITION'
                AND x.contract_number = z.contract_number
            GROUP BY
                z.contract_number 
        ) = 1
               AND (
            SELECT
                SUM(y.payment)
            FROM
                table_y y
            WHERE
                date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 6) AND sysdate
                AND internalname <> 'CONDITION'
                AND x.contract_number = y.contract_number
        ) > 1500 ) THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(DISTINCT damagenumber)
            FROM
                table z
            WHERE
                date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 6) AND sysdate
                AND internalname <> 'CONDITION'
                AND x.contract_number = z.contract_number
            GROUP BY
                z.contract_number 
            )
            ELSE
            0
            END) AS count_numbers,
FROM
    table_a x
GROUP BY
    x.contract_number,
    x.product_description,
    x.product;
```

The above is a simplified example. I have a lot of WHEN conditions in my query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  This is particularly important in a question about performance.  It is also unclear how many tables are involved with this question.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the intended logic all help.

Comment: Please share table structures and insert statement to populate sample data.

Comment: I think that the root cause of your problem is not in the case/when statement. Have you created indexes on the tables (table and table_y)? Perhaps these are big tables and the subqueries run for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this help

```
with tabletemp as (
    SELECT z.contract_number
    , COUNT(DISTINCT damagenumber) damagenumber_count
    FROM table z
    WHERE date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 6) AND sysdate AND internalname <> 'CONDITION'
    GROUP BY z.contract_number 
), tabletemp2 as (
    SELECT y.contract_number
    , SUM(y.payment) payment_sum
    FROM table_y y
    WHERE date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 6) AND sysdate AND internalname <> 'CONDITION'
    group by y.contract_number
)

SELECT
    contract_number,
    product_description,
    product,
    CASE WHEN ( x.produkt = 'product_name' AND tt.damagenumber_count = 1 AND tt2.payment_sum > 1500 ) THEN
            tt.damagenumber_count
            ELSE
            0
            END AS count_numbers,
FROM
    table_a x
    join tabletemp tt on (tt.contract_number = x.contract_number)
    join tabletemp2 tt2 on (tt2.contract_number = x.contract_number)
```

Maybe this query have some errors (I can't test) but you should try this way